# Check whether the given String matches the name of an Enum-element and return that element

Tags: java, string, enums, java-stream

Is it possible to check if the given string matches one of `enum`-names and then return that `enum`-element?

I tried this:

```
boolean isValid = Stream.of(Seniority.values())
                .map(Seniority::name)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .contains(experienceLevel.toUpperCase());

if (isValid) {
      return Seniority.valueOf(experienceLevel.toUpperCase());
} else {
      return null;
}
```

Is it possible to do all these actions by using stream only?

Comment: You are already doing it by one stream.

Comment: So... what is your question then?

Comment: Obviously, there is no reason to collect all elements into a `List`, just for a single invocation of `contains`. So you can replace the `collect … contains` with a terminal operation expression your actual intent, e.g. `boolean isValid = Stream.of(Seniority.values()) .map(Seniority::name) .anyMatch(experienceLevel::equalsIgnoreCase);` (assuming that your class follows the convention of all-uppercase constant names). Of course, it’s also simple to query the actual element in the first place

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to check if the given string matches one of enum-names
> and then return that enum-element?

You can use the generic method listed below for **any** type of `enum`.

Method `EnumSet.allOf()` expects a `Class<T>` object (*and* `T` *has to be an enum*) and returns a set of enum-constants.

Use `filter()` operation to find the matching *enum-element*. In place `toUpperCase()` you can use `equalsIgnoreCase()` which more expressive in this situation.

Method `findFirst()` returns an optional object if the stream is empty (i.e. match was not found). If you are not comfortable with it, you can apply `orEsle(null)` to return a string from the method. But I encourage you to get familiar with the capacities of the `Optional` instead of treating `null` as a legal value everywhere.

[*for more information on the Optional type take a look at this tutorial*](https://dev.java/learn/using-optionals/)

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> Optional<T> findMatchingEnumName(Class<T> enumClass,
                                                                   String target) {
    return EnumSet.allOf(enumClass).stream()
        .filter(element -> element.name().equalsIgnoreCase(target))
        .findFirst();
}
```

`main()` - demo, built-in *enum* `DayOfWeek` is used as an example.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(findMatchingEnumName(DayOfWeek.class, "saturday"));
}
```

**Output**

```
Optional[SATURDAY]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use only `valueOf()`

If the value doesn't exist you can catch it with IllegalArgumentException.

```
boolean isValid = true;
try {
    Seniority.valueOf(experienceLevel.toUpperCase());
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    isValid = false;
}
```